# How do i read, append and sort all the words of a text file in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

> Open the file `romeo.txt` and read it line by line. For each line,
>   split the line into a list of words using the `split()` function. The
>   program should build a list of words. For each word on each line check
>   to see if the word is already in the list and if not append it to the
>   list. When the program completes, sort and print the resulting words
>   in alphabetical order.

http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/romeo.txt

Here's my code :

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
for line in fh:
     for word in line.split():
          if word in line.split():
               line.split().append(word)
          if word not in line.split():
               continue
          print word
```

It only returns the last word of the last line, for some reason.

Comment: What are you expecting `line.split().append(word)` to do, exactly?

Comment: I tested your code:  it prints every word from every line, as I expected it would.  What do you expect when you call `line.split()`?  Which of your conditions ('word in ...' or 'word not in ...') do you expect to be true?

Comment: Am I misunderstanding the problem, or is it saying for every line in the file, split the line into words and check if each word in the resulting list is in said list? Isn't that redundant in that it would always be true? And what is the purpose of adding the word to the end of the list? Isn't it in the list twice then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of your loop, add a list to which you'll collect your words. Right now you are just discarding everything.

Your logic is also reverse, you are discarding words that you should be saving.

```
words = []
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
for line in fh:
     for word in line.split():
          if word not in words:
               words.append(word)
fh.close()

# Now you should sort the words list and continue with your assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, it uses a `set()` to build a unique list of words. Each word is also lower-cased so that "The" and "the" are treated the same.

```
import re

word_set = set()
re_nonalpha = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z ]+')

fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")

with open(fname, "r") as f_input:
    for line in f_input:
        line = re_nonalpha.sub(' ', line)  # Convert all non a-z to spaces

        for word in line.split():
            word_set.add(word.lower())

word_list = list(word_set)
word_list.sort()
print word_list
```

This will display the following list:

```
['already', 'and', 'arise', 'bits', 'breaks', 'but', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'has', 'is', 'it', 'juliet', 'kill', 'light', 'many', 'moon', 'pale', 'punctation', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'the', 'this', 'through', 'too', 'way', 'what', 'who', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']
```

Comment: I think a regex is overkill. The file that the OP is working with is already space delimited with no punctuation :)

Comment: Agreed, but I remembered an almost identical question and text, and that one had subtle punctuation all over the place which tripped things.

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted(set([w for l in open(fname) for w in l.split()]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand what `line.split()` is doing. `line.split()` will return a list containing the "words" that are in the string `line`. Here we interpret a "word" as "substring delimited by the space character". So if `line` was equal to `"Hello, World. I <3 Python"`, `line.split()` would return the list `["Hello,", "World.", "I", "<3", "Python"]`.

When you write `for word in line.split()` you are iterating through each element of that list. So the condition `word in line.split()` will always be true! What you really want is a cumulative list of "words you have already come across". At the top of the program you would create it using `DiscoveredWords = []`. Then for every word in every line you would check

```
if word not in DiscoveredWords:
    DiscoveredWords.append(word)
```

Got it? :) Now since it seems you are new to Python (welcome to the fun by the way) here is how I would have written the code:

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
with open(fname) as fh:
    words = [word for line in fh for word in line.strip().split()]
words = list(set(words))
words.sort()
```

Let's do a quick overview of this code so that you can understand what is going on:

`with open(fname) as fh` is a handy trick to remember. It allows you to ensure that your file gets closed! Once python exits the `with` block it will close the file for you automatically :D

`words = [word for line in fh for word in line.strip().split()]` is another handy trick. This is one of the more concise ways to get a list containing all of the words in a file! We are telling python to make a list by taking every line in the file (`for line in fh`) and then every word in that line (`for word in line.strip().split()`).

`words = list(set(words))` casts our list to a `set` and then back to a `list`. This is a quick way to remove duplicates as a `set` in python contains unique elements.

Finally we sort the list using `words.sort()`.

Hope this was helpful and instructive :)

Answer (score 0):

```
words=list()
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname).read()
fh=fh.split()

for word in fh:
    if word in words:
        continue
    else:
        words.append(word)
words.sort()
print(words)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.